# Nginx multiple domain directives

Tags: php, nginx

I'm using Nginx for a PHP project. Here is what I do in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {

server_name domain_a.com;
include /etc/nginx/main.conf; // listen, php directives, etc.

location ~ (.*)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
  }
}

server {

server_name domain_b.com;
include /etc/nginx/main.conf;

location ~ (.*)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
    
    // Specific to this domain
    auth_basic "Authentication";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/main.conf**

```
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 5M;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

root /var/www/web;
```

I have a lot of repetition in this code : The two `location` block could be merge in one for the two domains. I think I could use a if statement to add my specific code for domain_b but it's cleary not a recommanded way according to the documentation http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Do you have idea how I can do to respect the DRY concept ?

Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me I create a folder in my conf and call it `includes` for example and then you can include this where ever you want, for example

```
# /etc/nginx/includes/php.conf
location ~ (.*)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
}
```

Then in your configurations do something like this

```
server {
  server_name domain_a.com;
  include /etc/nginx/main.conf; // listen, php directives, etc.
  include /etc/nginx/includes/php.conf;
}

server {
  server_name domain_b.com;
  include /etc/nginx/main.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/includes/php.conf;
  auth_basic "Authentication";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was blocked because I try to include auth_basic instruction in location but it doesn't make sense

Comment: what do you mean by blocked?

Comment: I mean I was stuck on a problem

Comment: according to the documentation http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic you should be able to get auth_basic to work in a location block just fine